# How to have version concurrency control in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

Hibernate had a `<version>` property, I can't find anything in Slick's the documentation. Considering Hibernate actually manages this outside the database, is version concurrency control even something Slick was designed to handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slick doesn't have support for Versioning / Optimistic locking (see this [improvement request](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/378)).

Slick could definitely handle versioning, at least I cannot see a reason why not, but it looks like this is not really high priority for the Slick team, given that only a few people requested this feature.